# Guessing the third side of the triangle from the given two sides

Tags: geometry, triangles, triangle-inequality

[image: This is the question]My solution:-

We know that the length of the third side of a triangle is between the sum of the two sides and the difference between the two sides.

So according to the question the third side $x$, should follow this condition, $29>x>7$. So a probable value of $x$ is 28. So the answer should be II only. But this option is non-existent.

So is the question above or more specifically the options for the questions formulated wrongly?

If there's any problem in my question please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: It is the last option - all lengths are possible - the 29 if they are on a line.

Comment: Why do you think that $x$ is between $29$ and $7$. The third side (if the points are not on the same line) can be larger the $29$ but less than $40$ therefore the option $D$ is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem doesn't say that Q, R, and S are the vertices of a (non-degenerate) triangle, only that they are points on the plane.  They may all be on the same line. Therefore, you want $7\le x\le 29$, and (D) is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

They never said that $PQR$ was a triangle. If you allow all three points to be collinear, then $7$ and $29$ are also possible.